# SSD S.M.A.R.T. (SMART) 'Soft ECC Correction' attribute high on newish drive - Is this normal?

Tags: ssd, sata, storage, smart, diagnostic

On a 5-month old SATA SSD, the [S.M.A.R.T. (SMART)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) 'Soft ECC Correction' attribute's value is already large (58000).

***Is this normal?***

For reference, the 'Soft ECC Correction' attribute is SMART attribute #204 (0xCC).

The total power-on hours (POH) for the drive is ~2500 hours, but the drive is used probably less than an "average" amount, meaning it's not doing any heavy lifting.  It's not used for any intensive operations like swap files, caches, or virtual memory.

Outside of this questionable SMART value, there are no indications of any problems.

---

* S.M.A.R.T. = Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology

Comment: Soft (i.e. correctable) errors when reading NAND flash is nowadays considered normal.  The use of ECC is required for modern NAND chips by manufacturers, and specified with a minimum capability number of bits (per byte) that can be corrected.  Maybe 12 years ago you could buy NAND chips that had very low error rates for a reasonable price, but not any more.

Comment: Is your box showing any slowdowns, specially when writing to disk? Do you have a back-up set up?

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the helpful info.  Sounds like it could be a great answer.  Are you saying that NAND chips are now a lower quality?  If so, are the primary reasons increased bit density and mass production?

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea No noticeable performance issues.  Everything is faster (and quieter!) than the HDD it replaced, but that's the only comparison I can make.  Regarding backups, always!

Comment: Quality is in the eye of the beholder. The premise is that it's okay if bit errors occur as long as they are detected and are correctable.  Yes, those are two of several reasons.  Note also that NAND controllers have improved a lot, and now handle the error correction in HW.  So a lengthy error correction code (e.g. 20 vs 13 bytes needed for correction capability of 12 vs 8 bits in a "sector") is mostly a storage burden rather than a computational one.